# android EditText enable and disable

Tags: android, view, bluetooth, android-edittext

I am creating an app to communicate via bluetooth. I want first to enable my entire view until the connection establishes. Then when I click a button, I want a text view to be enabled to send a string via bluetooth.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where you can just ask for code. Do some ground work before posting a question. Show members what you have already tried against a problem, possibly with some code snippets. Only then others be able to effectively help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html for bluetooth connection establishment. To enable or disabled TextView (or any view) use setEnabled(boolean enable) method e.g.:

To enable:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
textView.setEnabled(true);
```

To disable:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
textView.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! I'll try and feedback you

Comment: Thanks it works. But I want to make it enable at runtime. How can I do it?

Comment: It is enabled by default. You can pass in xml layout file:

    <TextView>
       ...
       enabled="true"
       ...
    </TextView>

Or in onCreate method to be sure that it is enabled from the very beginning.